# Why is $d^3\vec{v} = 4\pi v^2dv$ in integration if the speed is isotropic?

Tags: coordinate-systems, integration

in my galaxies textbook it says that $d^3\vec{v} = 4\pi v^2dv$ for integration if the speed is isotropic, where does this come from?
example: In my statistical mechanics book it was said that the number of standing-wave solutions with an impulsvector in the interval $[\vec{p},\vec{p} + d\vec{p}]$ is in 3 dimensions:
$$f(\vec{p})d^3\vec{p} = \frac{V}{h^3}(4\pi p^2dp) = \frac{V}{h^3}d\vec{p}.$$

Comment: Notational quirk: you left side is a vector so your right side should also be a vector.... or alternatively your left side shouldn't be a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right expression should be
$$\int d\mathbf{v}\rightarrow 4\pi \int_0^\infty v^2dv$$
This could be conclude from
$$\int d\mathbf{v}\rightarrow \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \int_0^\pi d\theta \sin\theta \int_0^\infty v^2dv=4\pi \int_0^\infty v^2dv$$

Where in the last step we have to perform angular integral.

Comment: Oh ok the v^2 arises like r^2 in the metric, got it now thanks! Will accept when allowed :)

Comment: The comment of ZeroTheHero also applies to this answer. The notation used is rather misleading.

Answer (score 1):

That's a direct consequence of the transformation in spherical coordinates. In fact given a general vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with components $(x,y,z)$, we can go to spherical coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$ and the infinitesimal volume becomes $$d^3x \equiv dxdydz  = r^2\sin\theta\, dr\,d\theta \,d\phi$$ where $r^2\sin\theta$ is the Jacobian of the transformation. If we're dealing with isotropic quantities, they only depend on $r$, so they are of the form $f(r)$ which means that, when integrating them, the angular part can be carried out directly yielding a factor of $4\pi$ $$\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\int\limits_0^\pi\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi = 4\pi$$
This leads to the equality you gave which is $d^3x = 4\pi r^2\,dr$.